# Rails/JS - Like button with AJAX in 2018

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've got the following project: **(not using acts_as_votable gem, apart from all the other threads I found here!)**

There is a Beat model which has_many :likes and belongs_to :user, a beat has_many :likes and belongs_to :beat. In my LikesController I got a create and a destroy action to create a new like whenever a Beat is liked.
The liking functionality works quite well, however, the page reloads with each like/unlike. Using AJAX I want to show the current like status (solid heart = liked) without having to reload the page or redirect_to somewhere.

controllers/likes_controller.rb:

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @beat = Beat.find(params[:beat_id])

    if already_liked?
      flash[:notice] = "You can't like more than once!"
    else
      @beat.likes.create(user_id: current_user.id)
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @beat = Beat.find(params[:beat_id])
    @like = @beat.likes.find(params[:id])
    if !already_liked?
      flash[:notice] = "Can't unlike!"
    else
      @like.destroy
    end
  end

  private
    def already_liked?
      Like.where(user_id: current_user.id, beat_id: params[:beat_id]).exists?
    end
end
```

views/beats/show.html.haml

```
= @beat.likes.count
= (@beat.likes.count) == 1 ? 'Like' : 'Likes'

- previous_like = @beat.likes.find { |like| like.user_id == current_user.id}
- if previous_like
  = button_to 'Unlike', beat_like_path(@beat, previous_like), method: :delete, remote: true 
- else
  = button_to 'Like', beat_likes_path(@beat), method: :post, remote: true 

= link_to 'Back', :beats
```

By using `remote: true` I can send an AJAX request to my controller, but first how do I handle this in my controller? How do I send back a JSON/XML ajax-like response and last: how do I handle this response from my controller with JS to display in my show.html.haml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> controllers/likes_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @beat = Beat.find(params[:beat_id])

    if already_liked?
      flash.now[:notice] = "You can't like more than once!"
    else
      @beat.likes.create(user_id: current_user.id)
    end
  end
```

> views/beats/show.html.erb

```
<p id="likes-count"><%= pluralize(@beat.likes.count, 'Like') %></p>
<div id="like-button"><%= like_button_tag @beat, previous_like %></div>
```

> helpers/beats_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def like_button_tag beat, previous_like
    return button_to 'Unlike', beat_like_path(beat, previous_like), method: :delete, remote: true if previous_like
    button_to 'Like', beat_likes_path(beat), method: :post, remote: true
  end
end
```

> views/beats/create.js.erb

```
$('#likes-count').html('<%= pluralize(@beat.likes.count, 'Like') %>');
$('#like-button').html('<%= like_button_tag @beat, previous_like %>');
```

you can also use haml instead of erb

Comment: let me know if there is any problem

Comment: happy to help @F.Amg

Comment: Hey one question Sikandar: I just found out the create.js.erb isn't being loaded/used somehow, when I delete the content its still working, what was the create.js.erb even used for? I wanted to get rid of the scrolling to top when I like/unlike a Beat. I tried to use e.preventDefault on the #like-button within the create.js.erb but nothing in there is being loaded/executed?

Comment: @F.Amg create.js.erb is the view that renders for `remote: true` requests... if create.js.erb is not working it means that requests  may not be rendering as js format and page whole page is being refreshed

Comment: So do I have to adjust my controller? At which exact action, should I use something like "render :json =>" then? I am kind of confused right now :p!

Comment: can you share your codebase on Github maybe? so I can take a look